# How to insert an array value to an existing JSON document?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

Given a column containing a JSON document, I can use `JSON_SET()` to set a key in the JSON document to a value. Supported values are `null`, `true`, `false`, numbers and strings; but I can't figure out how to set an array.

The [example in the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_insert/) (for `JSON_INSERT()`, but it works the same) weirdly shows how a naive user might try and fail to set an array value, but kind of lampshades it; if you look closely you will find that the array was converted to a string.

I figured out a workaround where you first use:

```
JSON_SET(col, '$.field', "first value")
-- {"field": "first value"}
```

and then:

```
JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(col, '$.field', "second value")
-- {"field": ["first value", "second value"]}
```

But there are all kinds of problems with that, not the least of it is that it can't be used to set an array with less than 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON_INSERT/JSON_REPLACE/JSON_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) will happily accept a JSON document as the *value*:

```
SELECT JSON_INSERT('{"foo": "bar"}', '$.new', JSON_ARRAY('one', 'two', 'three'))
/*
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "new": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
*/
```

Note that:

- `JSON_SET()` replaces existing values and adds nonexisting values.
- `JSON_INSERT()` inserts values without replacing existing values.
- `JSON_REPLACE()` replaces only existing values.

If you want to append values to an array that may/may not already exist then chain the functions in this order:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_INSERT('{"foo": "bar"}', '$.new', JSON_ARRAY()), '$.new', 'four')
/*
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "new": ["four"]
}
*/
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(JSON_INSERT('{"foo": "bar", "new": ["one", "two", "three"]}', '$.new', JSON_ARRAY()), '$.new', 'four')
/*
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "new": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
}
*/
```

Comment: Wow. That was not at all obvious: `select JSON_ARRAY("a", "b"); -- > ["a", "b"]` and `select JSON_SET('{"foo":"bar"}', '$.baz', '["a", "b"]'); -- > '{"foo": "bar", "baz": "[\"a\", \"b\"]"}'` but `select JSON_SET('{"foo":"bar"}', '$.baz', JSON_ARRAY("a", "b")); -- > '{"foo": "bar", "baz": ["a", "b"]}'`

Comment: Yes. `'[1, 2]'` looks like JSON but it is still a string just like `'whatever'`. Use one of the functions from [Functions That Create JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html) which return JSON datatype.

Comment: Another important note, which I hit my head against a couple of times - at least in MariaDB the `JSON_*` functions have a failure more where they just return `NULL` instead of throwing an error, so if using them in an `UPDATE` statement, it is recommended to wrap them in `IFNULL()` - like this: `UPDATE table SET col = IFNULL(JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(col, '$.key', 'val'), col) ...`

Comment: You can use `SHOW WARNINGS` after executing such queries to identify the broken JSON and fix it.

Comment: the problem is that the "broken JSON" is often completely valid JSON in the database. For example, `JSON_REPLACE('{}','$.foo','bar')` returns `{}` correctly, but `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('{}','$.foo','bar')` returns `NULL`, which might be surprising, and if you use it blindly in an `UPDATE` statement - you just lost some data and probably caused any future operations to fail.

Comment: Both behavior are as expected. `{}` is an object, not an array so ARRAY_* functions should fail. Use `SHOW WARNINGS` command to see why MySQL returned null

Comment: No warnings are shown for the `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` example above. It should add an array for key `foo` - i.e. the result should be `{"foo":["bar"]}`, if the function can auto-vivify (it does know to convert single values to arrays, so it seems like a reasonable expectation) or `{}` if it specifically doesn't want to auto-vivify - like `JSON_REPLACE` behaves for non-existent fields. Regardless this behavior is undocumented and could destroy data in `UPDATE` commands.